# Javascript: check for ::after in element

Tags: javascript, dom, element, detect

I have a very simple element:
[image]
How can I check if this element contains the ::after using Javascript?

(I have the element using `document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]`)

I don't know how the thing works, and I don't need to know, I just need the code to see if it exists...

In some cases the element looks like this:
[image]
I need to be able to detect both cases, if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link, explains how to use it in plain JavaScript (might only work in newer browsers): http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Edit: if you're looking to edit what the content of the :after is, reference this SO question: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Tried it, works: `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h2'), ':after').getPropertyValue('background')` is different when the ::after isn't there, so I can work with it!

Comment: Glad to hear it - I was looking at the jQuery selectors (https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but it doesn't seem like they have one for that since it's more a CSS thing than HTML one...

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
var pre = onload; // assign previous onload if any
onload = function(){ // onload wrapper start
if(pre)pre(); // execute previous onload in the new onload
var doc = document, h2a = doc.getElementsByTagName('h2');
var afterIn = [], afterOut = [];
for(var i=0,l=h2a.length; i<l; i++){
  var h2 = h2a[i];
  if(h2.value.match(/\:\:after/)){
    afterIn.push(h2);
  }
  else{
    afterOut.push(h2);
  }
}
for(var i=0,l=afterIn.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(afterIn[i].value);
}
for(var i=0,l=afterOut.length; i<l; i++){
  console.log(afterOut[i].value);
}
} // onload wrapper end
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].value` appears to always be undefined

Comment: Run it `onload`, in the `<head>` using an external `<script type='text/javascript' src='externalJS.js'></script>`.